# Synchronize database of Firebase with Swift 4 language

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, firebase

I am new at swift 4 programming. I try to show some data(actually they are child names) from database of firebase. When view did load, I can take them and show on tableView but it is not working real time. When I delete some data from firebase, I need to refresh(go back and load again) the viewController. If I refresh the tableView with timer, all data append from its end. If I, firstly, delete after append new data to tableView. It is jittering. Is there anyway to synchronize this tableView with firebase, without these problems?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.keepSynced(true)

        let userRef = self.ref.child("Users").child(Username).child("Schedule")
        userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                self.myList.append(key)
                self.CourseList.append(key)
                self.LessonsTableView.reloadData()
            }
            // Lessons are taking and after, they are locating under phone's memory!
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.CourseList, forKey: "LessonsArray")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        })
}

//Setting up our table
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myList.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = LessonsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! LessonsTableViewCell
        cell.myLabell.text = myList[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let Dummy:String = myList[indexPath.row] as Any as! String
        let Selected:String = (Dummy as NSString) as Any as! String
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Selected, forKey: "Selected")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NextPage", sender: self)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase's task is a network task which normally runs on a background (lower priority) thread. But tableView.reloadData() is an UI task. So you probably need to execute UI related codes by following codes.

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            self.myList.append(key)
            self.CourseList.append(key)
            self.LessonsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: To make it simple, you can just use DispatchQueue.main.sync {} to cover the code from the line "for child in snapshot.children {" to the line "UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()". On the other hand, just execute whole firebase observer callback in the UI thread.

Comment: I couldn't write here the code. Please look at my last post in here.

Answer (score 0):

it is giving an error like this,

```
    let userRef = self.ref.child("Users").child(Username).child("Schedule")
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            self.myList.append(key)
            self.CourseList.append(key)
            self.LessonsTableView.reloadData()
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.CourseList, forKey: "LessonsArray")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    })
```